# Toad gives only date in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datetime, toad

When I do a query `SELECT t.NAME, t.SOME_DATE FROM MY_TABLE t` in toad I get dates as `14-FEB-13` with no time information! In the table browser it gives full date and time. How can this be changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the default setting for a session.  If you want to change it,

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Or, change your query to

```
SELECT t.NAME, to_char(t.SOME_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM MY_TABLE t
```

( the above is just an example, you can format whatever way you want in the format string, ie. 'MM/DD/YYYY, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the same results as you see in the table browser when executing SQL directly (without changing your settings), use "Editor\Execute Statement (F9)" instead of "Editor\Execute as Script".

"Execute statement" displays data in a Toad grid, so the formatting will always be the same as the formatting you see in the table browser, while "Execute script" uses your session information, as explained in [OldProgrammer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745544/oldprogrammer) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14904768/622391).

**Execute statement:**

[image: execute statement]

**Execute script:**

[image: execute script]